# How to map this object in RESTKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit, restkit-0.20

I have JSON of following kind

```
{
    "Client": {
        "FirstName": "String",
        "LastName": "String",
        "Email": "String",
        "Password": "String",
        "PhoneNumber": "String",
        "Token": "String"
    },
    "ErrorMessage": "String",
    "FriendlyMessage": "String"
}
```

I know that while mapping if I specify a key path then RestKit matches fields from object specified, in this case `Client`, to the code I am using for that is as follows

```
[responseMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
    @"FirstName": @"FirstName",
    @"LastName": @"LastName",
    @"Email": @"Email",
    @"PhoneNumber": @"PhoneNumber",
    @"Token": @"Token",
    @"Password": @"Password",
    @"ErrorMessage": @"ErrorMessage"}];

RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:responseMapping
                                                                                        method:RKRequestMethodPOST
                                                                                   pathPattern:nil
                                                                                       keyPath:@"Client"
                                                                                   statusCodes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:200]];
```

But I have two additional fields to map which aren't under client object. How do I map `ErrorMessage` and `FriendlyMessage` fields ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you wouldn't want to map them into your `client` object, you would want to map them into some other object. You would usually use a different object and response mapping, where the response mapping uses a different key path.

If for some reason you did want them in the same object then you could look at using the `@metadata` / `@parent` to get to the parent (https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/pull/1435).

Comment: oh yeah i now i got it we can add multiple mappings to RKObjectManager, thanks a lot , i will add another object for errors